# Unable to mount a file in the docker

Tags: docker

I got the following command to run the docker (following the running command in https://hub.docker.com/r/manios/nagios )

```
DOCKER_CONFIGS=$(pwd)

docker run --name nagios  \
  -v $DOCKER_CONFIGS/conf/etc/:/opt/nagios/etc/ \
  -v $DOCKER_CONFIGS/conf/var:/opt/nagios/var/ \
  -v $DOCKER_CONFIGS/conf/custom-plugins:/opt/Custom-Nagios-Plugins \
  -v $DOCKER_CONFIGS/conf/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf:/etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf \
  -p 0.0.0.0:8990:80 \
  manios/nagios:latest
```

And I'm getting the following error

docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: error during container init: error mounting "/home/pi/docker/nagios/conf/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf" to rootfs at "/etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf": mount /home/pi/docker/nagios/conf/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf:/etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf (via /proc/self/fd/6), flags: 0x5000: not a directory: unknown: Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host path exists and is the expected type.
ERRO[0001] error waiting for container:

The issue is that docker tries to mount a folder to a file. Inside the docker container I can see /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf as a file. and $DOCKER_CONFIGS/conf/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf creating as a folder. How do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked whether `/home/pi/docker/nagios/conf/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf` is existing on your machine?

I could imagine that if this path (and file) doesn't exist, it can't be mounted.

Answer (score 0):

> $DOCKER_CONFIGS/conf/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf creating as a folder. How do I resolve this issue?

Create `$DOCKER_CONFIGS/conf/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf` file before starting the contianer.